# Playing Audio Base64s With No Delay

Tags: javascript, audio, electron

I have an `Object` with couple of base64s (Audio) inside. The base64s will start to play with a `keydown` event. In some situations (when the Base64 size is a little high), a delay will occur before playing. Is there any way to remove this delay, or at least reduce it?

*App Witten in JavaScript And Running On Electron*

```
//audio base64s object
var audio = {A: new Audio('base64[1]'), B: new Audio('base64[2]'), C: new Audio('base64[3]')};

//audio will start plying with key down
function keydown(ev) {
    if (audio[String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode)].classList.contains('holding') == false) {
        audio[String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode)].classList.add('holding');
        if (audio[String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode)].paused) {
            playPromise = audio[String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode)].play();
                if (playPromise) {
                playPromise.then(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                            // Follow up operation
                        }, audio.duration * 1000); 
                    }).catch(function() {
                        // Audio loading failure
                });        
        } else {
            audio[String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode)].currentTime = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using base64 in the first place?  There is almost never a good reason.  In any case, if you need responsive audio you need the Web Audio API, where you have more control over what's buffered and when it plays.

Comment: I am adding audio base64, to objects after they(Audios) dropped in app, is there better way for saving it in a special file (text file)?

Comment: Use the file reference directly.  You can use `URL.createObjectURL()`.  No, you don't want a text file of any kind... it's binary data.

Comment: Is reading by directory faster than reading a base64?

Comment: Think about it this way... you could just use the blob directly in its binary format.  *Or*, you could do what you're doing and read the entire file, convert it to base64 (adding 33% of pointless overhead in memory usage and wasted CPU), make a few copies of that string in memory as you use in your script, then have the underlying browser turn around and decode it, making another copy of that whole thing in memory and wasting CPU in the process, just to get it back to the binary resource you started with... that then has to be decoded.  Which do you think is faster?

Comment: Thank you for your cool, professional, and straightforward answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for being cranky... I get that way when I take the time to help people and they flip right around and effectively say, "are you sure that works"?  Especially when they could have trivially tested it themselves to see.  And if I'm honest, I'm also frustrated as I see this exact same type of question several times a day on Stack Overflow.  If I could rid the internet of these bad tutorials that tell people to use base64 for every single thing, I would.  So, please don't take it too personally.

Comment: You are right, only after one time testing this can be easily understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a complete example for you, and annotated below.

Some key takeaways:

- If you need any sort of expediency or control over timing, you need to use the Web Audio API.  Without it, you have no control over the buffering or other behavior of audio playback.
- Don't use base64 for this.  You don't need it.  Base64 encoding is a method for encoding binary data into a text format.  There is no text format here... therefore it isn't necessary.  When you use base64 encoding, you add 33% overhead to the storage, you use CPU, memory, etc.  There is no reason for it here.
- Do use the appropriate file APIs to get what you need.  To decode an audio sample, we need an array buffer.  Therefore, we can use the `.arrayBuffer()` method on the file itself to get that.  This retains the content in binary the entire time and allows the browser to memory-map if it wants to.

The code:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
let buffer;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
    // Start the AudioContext, now that we have user ineraction
    audioContext.resume();

    // Ensure we actually have at least one file before continuing
    if ( !(e.currentTarget.files && e.currentTarget.files[0]) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Read the file and decode the audio
    buffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(
        await e.currentTarget.files[0].arrayBuffer()
    );
  });
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    // Ensure we've loaded audio
    if (!buffer) {
    return;
  }

  // Create the node that will play our previously decoded buffer
  bufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  bufferSourceNode.buffer = buffer;

  // Hook up the buffer source to our output node (speakers, headphones, etc.)
  bufferSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  // Adjust pitch based on the key we pressed, just for fun
  bufferSourceNode.detune.value = (e.keyCode - 65) * 100;

  // Start playing... right now
  bufferSourceNode.start();
});
```

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/bradisbell/sc9jpxvn/1/